# ImapIdleChannelAdapter doesn't get message content

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, imap, mime

I'm using this code to read mail from an IMAP server:

```
@EnableIntegration
public class MailIntegration implements HasLogger {

    @Bean
    public ImapIdleChannelAdapter messageChannel(ImapMailReceiver receiver) {
        var receiver = new ImapMailReceiver("imaps://...");
        var adapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(receiver);
        adapter.setOutputChannelName("imapChannel");
        return adapter;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "imapChannel")
    public void handleMessage(MimeMessage message) {
        getLogger().info("Got message!");

        var subject = message.getSubject();
        getLogger().info("Subject: {}", subject);

        var contentType = message.getContentType();
        getLogger().info("ContentType: {}", contentType);

        var content = message.getContent();
        if (content instanceof String) {
            var text = (String) content;
            getLogger().info("Content: {}", text);
            getLogger().info("Length: {}", text.length());
        } else {
            getLogger().info("Other content: {}", content);
        }
    }
}
```

If I send plain text e-mail, the handler kicks in and it logs:

```
INFO : Got message!
INFO : Subject: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
INFO : ContentType: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
INFO : Content:
INFO : Length: 0
```

If I send an HTML e-mail, the handler kicks in and it logs:

```
INFO : Got message!
INFO : Subject: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
INFO : ContentType: text/html; charset="utf-8"
INFO : Content:
INFO : Length: 0
```

The subject is correct (and so are headers) but the content is always empty for plain and HTML e-mails both.

Also, I would expect to receive a `multipart` message for HTML, not just the `text/html` part. In fact, if I check the raw message in my e-mail client I see:

```
From: Giovanni Lovato <giovanni.lovato@...>
To: Test <test@...>
Subject: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
... lots of other header lines ...
Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_3642854791_1171496246"

> This message is in MIME format. Since your mail reader does not understand
this format, some or all of this message may not be legible.

--B_3642854791_1171496246
Content-type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

--B_3642854791_1171496246
Content-type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</body>
</html>


--B_3642854791_1171496246--
```

So it seems like the `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` is already extracting the HTML part and passing that to the handler, with all the original headers; still without content, though.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try to set `simpleContent` to `true` on the `ImapMailReceiver`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#mail-inbound. Also be sure that `ImapMailReceiver` is declared as a bean. Not sure what is going on with your `messageChannel` configuration now. Side note: the `ChannelAdapter` is indeed not a *channel* - would be great do not confuse yourself and don't name such a bean as a `messageChannel`.

Comment: Setting `simpleContent` to `true` indeed works! Damn confusing, "simple content" what does that mean? Event JavaDocs are difficult to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `simpleContent` to `true` on the `ImapMailReceiver`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#mail-inbound

When this is true, the content of the mail body is fetched on demand:

```
@Override
    public Object getContent() throws IOException, MessagingException {
        if (AbstractMailReceiver.this.simpleContent) {
            return super.getContent();
        }
        else {
            return this.content;
        }
    }
```

instead of eager fetch otherwise:

```
IntegrationMimeMessage(MimeMessage source) throws MessagingException {
        super(source);
        this.source = source;
        if (AbstractMailReceiver.this.simpleContent) {
            this.content = null;
        }
        else {
            Object complexContent;
            try {
                complexContent = source.getContent();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                complexContent = "Unable to extract content; see logs: " + e.getMessage();
                AbstractMailReceiver.this.logger.error("Failed to extract content from " + source, e);
            }
            this.content = complexContent;
        }
    }
```

In the version `5.2` we have introduced:

```
/**
 * Configure a {@code boolean} flag to close the folder automatically after a fetch (default) or
 * populate an additional {@link IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor#CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE} message header instead.
 * It is the downstream flow's responsibility to obtain this header and call its {@code close()} whenever
 * it is necessary.
 * <p> Keeping the folder open is useful in cases where communication with the server is needed
 * when parsing multipart content of the email with attachments.
 * <p> The {@link #setSimpleContent(boolean)} and {@link #setHeaderMapper(HeaderMapper)} options are not
 * affected by this flag.
 * @param autoCloseFolder {@code false} do not close the folder automatically after a fetch.
 * @since 5.2
 */
public void setAutoCloseFolder(boolean autoCloseFolder) {
```

i believe this one should help you as well.

Comment: Not sure I understand the `setAutoCloseFolder` method: setting `simpleContent = true` I can fetch e-mail attachments, which is what I need, but do I need to close something manually afterward? If I set this "auto-close" flag, will I be able to fetch attachments in the handler?

Comment: Yes, you will be able, but you also would need to close a folder yourself. Although it is going to be closed in the end of your application anyway. There are some cases when we can't fetch all the content from the message if the folder is closed. You might not consider that if a `simpleContent` is enough for you.

Comment: See [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4098) and [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4299) for more background.